# Flutter : Keyboard pops up after Dialog is destroyed

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

**Problem** :

When login button is pressed, a progress indicator is shown. But, when it's done, keyboard automatically pops up even if it was not showing eariler.

**What I think** :

I think that because the last focus was on `TextField`, the current focus is switched back onto it after the process.

**What my code is doing** :

On login button pressed, it triggers `showDialog` method.
After that it waits (`await`) for the process to finish.
After that, `Navigator.pop(context)` is called so the `Dialog` can be destroyed.

And that's when the keyboard shows up again.

**Visual** :

[image: GIF]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

before showing the dialogue, do this,`FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();`